# Strip html tags and content with specified attributes

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have lots of text marked up like this:

```
<span class="section">[<a href="blablabla">Section</a>]</span>
```

I need to remove everything that has **class="section"** including span tags and text inside it. I'm looking for a regex or an alternativeto automate this task.

Any clues?

edit: Im up to anything that helps me solve this, i thought regex was the easier way. i'm coding in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Contrary to the silly non-answers, it's possible, just not easy with a regex. More trivial would be [tag:querypath] which allows for: `print htmlqp($html)->remove(".section")->top()->html();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your section-class tags don't contain elements of the same type (e.g. you do not have spans containing spans) you can do this quite easily with a regex.

The following is the simplest:

```
$stripped = preg_replace('@<span class="section">.*?</span>@', '', $input);
```

This, if you need it, allows for any tag, any other attributes, and any other classes:

```
$stripped = preg_replace('@<(\w+)[^>]*class="[^"]*section[^"]*"[^>]*>.*?</\1>@', '', $input);
```